# Invoke-RestMethod to Pass Parameter with Value that's a Hash Table

Tags: rest, powershell

I've been searching high and low and trying different variations, but I can't seem to get this right.

I'm using a RESTful API and the parameter is "log_data" and the value is a hash table @{}. I keep receiving an error from the API saying "Request body must be populated with the body parameter".

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$JSONHashTable = 
@{
"auto_discovered"= "false"
"coalesce_events"= "true"
"credibility"= 5
"description"= "Type @ SERVERNAME"
"enabled"= "true"
"gateway"= "false"
"group_ids"= @(11111)
"internal"= "true"
"language_id"= 1
"log_extension_id"= 153
"name"= "Type @ SERVERNAME"
"protocol_parameters"= @(
@{
 id= '41040'
 name= "RootDirectory"
 value= "C:\Temp\"
}
@{
 id= '41060'
 name= "MonitoringAlgorithm"
 value= "Continuous Monitoring"
}
@{
 id= '41080'
 name= "OnlyMonitorFilesCreatedToday"
 value= "false"
}
@{
 id= '41100'
 name= "FileReaderPolicy"
 value= "UnicodeLogFile"
}
@{
 id= '41000'
 name= "identifier"
 value= "192.168.8.6"
}
@{
 id= '41005'
 name= "Local_System"
 value= "true"
}
@{
 id= '41050'
 name= "FilenamePattern"
 value= "locallog.*\.txt"
}
@{
 id= '41090'
 name= "FileMonitorPolicy"
 value= "FileMonitorNoFSRedirect"
}
@{
 id= '41120'
 name= "ThrottleTimeout"
 value= "Wi @ SERVERNAME"
}
@{
 id= '41110'
 name= "WinInstanceName"
 value= "5000"
}
)
"protocol_type_id"= 41
"requires_deploy"= "true"
"store_event_payload"= "true"
"target_collector_id"= 235
"type_id"= 39
"win_internal_destination_id"= 14
}

$body = @{"log_data"=$JSONHashTable} | ConvertTo-Json 
$LogRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -body $body -Uri $LogURI -Header @{"SEC"= $apiKey }
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from "log_data" and retry. Check here http://wahlnetwork.com/2016/02/18/using-powershell-arrays-and-hashtables-with-json-formatting/

Comment: I tried that and I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you send your POST to a different endpoint and look at it with something like Postman, Fiddler, etc?

Comment: what does $JSONHashTable look like?

Comment: @zdan Just updated my original post with this.

Answer (score 2):

The hashtable that you are supplying to `ConvertTo-Json` is 3 layers deep. By default, `ConvertTo-Json` will only convert the first 2 layers, so your body is not fully converted. You can change the desired depth manually:

```
$body = @{"log_data"=$JSONHashTable} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

Comment: Thank you. While this was certainly an issue. I still receive the same error.

Comment: @MrMr Is it the server that's replying with that error?

Comment: Yes, it's the server. "Request body 
must be populated for body parameter \"log_data\""}

Comment: Then the solution has probably more to do with the API than powershell.